# Как в JMeter задать в User Defined Variables результат SQL запроса?

Tags: jmeter, variable

Пример. В User Defined Variables можно жестко вбить значения. А как использовать там результаты SQL запроса? Просто вбить в поле SQL запрос не помогает - тогда подставляется именно сам запрос, а не его результаты.

Answer (score 0):

Никак, User Defined Variables выполняется **перед всеми остальными элементами** и только один раз (см. [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder))

Если вы хотите выполнить SQL запрос и сохранить его результат как глобальную переменную - делайте это в [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) и используйте функцию [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty), потом в основной Thread Group вы сможете прочитать значение в User Defined Variables при помощи функции [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

Пример Test Plan:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]